# How can I predict how much money I will lose if I lose a battle?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

If I lose a battle (i.e. all 6 of my pokemon faint), how much money will I lose?

Comment: [According to Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Black_out), in FireRed, LeafGreen, and the 4th generation, it's based on a formula: MaxLevel * BadgeMultiplier, where BadgeMultiplier depends on the number of badges you have (8 if you have 0 badges, 16 for 1, then 24, 36, 48, 60, 80, 100, 120). I *suspect* it's the same, or at least similar, in the 5th generation, but I admit that I'm not sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The amount of money you will lose since FireRed and LeafGreen (with the exception of Emerald) is determined by:

Money = Level * Base Payout

Level is the highest level pokemon of yours and the base payout is based on the number of badges you have.

Badges/Payout

- 0/8
- 1/16
- 2/24
- 3/36
- 4/48
- 5/60
- 6/80
- 7/100
- 8/120

For example, if you have 5 gym badges and your top level pokemon is 30, your money lost for defeat would be 30 * 60 = 1800.

[Source (bulbapedia)](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Black_out)

While it is possible the bulbapedia article is outdated given the site's recent downtime, [serebii's battle changes page](http://serebii.net/blackwhite/battle.shtml) lists no change to the payout system in gen V.

Comment: Is that top level Pokemon overall (i.e. in a box on the PC) or in your party at the time of fainting?

Comment: @Robotnik The Bulbapedia page implies it's your party: `For example, if the player loses to another Trainer with only a Level 96 Venusaur in his or her party`...